# Regex to match Version number not starting with x.y

Tags: regex, msbuild, regex-negation

I am trying to find version numbers in AssemblyInfo.cs files that don't start with the Major.Minor numbers I am building. I have tried various versions of this but it doesn't do what I want - can anyone help with my RegEx?

```
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File Condition="'$(BuildNumber)' != ''"
                                           TaskAction="Replace"
                                           RegexPattern="Version\(\&quot;(?:![$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor)])\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)\&quot;\)"
                                           Replacement="Version(&quot;$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).0.0&quot;)"
                                           Files="$(AssemblyInfoFiles)" />
```

Note that I am using the AssemblyInfo class inthe extension pack but the above is for the initial set.

**EDIT**
Here is the working version I am using with @Omega's help. Note that i am using a VersionMajorMinor property I already have.

```
        <!-- Update all the assembly info files with generated version info -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File TaskAction="Replace"
                                           RegexPattern="Version\(\&quot;(?!$(VersionMajorMinor)\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\&quot;\)"
                                           Replacement="Version(&quot;$(VersionMajorMinor).0.0&quot;)"
                                           Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Version\(\&quot;(?!$(VersionMajor)\.$(VersionMinor)\.)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\&quot;\)`

Comment: Thanks Omega I had to change it slightly Version\(\&quot;(?!$(VersionMajor)\.$(VersionMinor))\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\&quot;\)

Comment: @Mark - Why did you remove `\.` behind VersionMinor? Imagine your VersionMajor is 1 and VersionMinor is 2, without such `\.` it will match also string `Version(&quot;1.20.3.4&quot;)`

Comment: You're right, not sure how I deleted that - thanks for the catch